# Attaching click listener to component rendered via map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering a list by using map function of javascript, and I want to add click listener to the elements of that list but I am enable to do so.

Here's the code link - https://codesandbox.io/s/oqvvr1n3vq

I want to console log `Hello` whenever `h1 tag is clicked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onClick` expect a function (event handler), but you are assigning a value, it means that console.log will get executed immediately without clicking on any tag.

Solution is- Create a function in `Dummy` component and use that function as click handler.

Like this:

```
onClick={() => console.log("Hello", props.display)}
```

or

```
const Dummy = props => {
  const handler = () => console.log("Hello", props.display);

  return (
    <h1 style={{ border: "1px solid black" }} onClick={handler}>
      {props.display}
    </h1>
  );
};
```

[Working Example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/p3p0mxm1x7)